# Missing POST and GET with Apache Alias

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have a Symfony project with the file `index.php` in `/var/www/public`.

I want to only allow access to the website using a virtual `generate` folder, so the site should always be accessed like this: `http://localhost/generate`.

`http://localhost/` should just throw a 404.

I'm using the following Apache config, but the `$_POST` and `$_GET` globals are missing when I debug my script (I'm firing a POST request from Postman). It works when I reset my Apache config to just serve from the root without any alias..what is going on?

I'm not using any .htaccess files in my `/var/www/public` folder.

The Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      <FilesMatch ".+(\.php)$">
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9100/
      </FilesMatch>

      DocumentRoot "/var/www/public"

      Alias /generate /var/www/public
      <Location /generate>
          AllowOverride All
      </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Symfony, you can simply define routes for `/generate` and nothing for `/`

routes.yaml

```
Generate:
    path: /generate
    controller: ControllerNamespaceAndName::MethodName
```

Because you don't use route definition for `/` when accessing `http://localhost/`, symfony's kernel will throw a 404

Comment: I'd rather not install the routing component just for this redirect, but if no-one comes with a working Apache solution this will be my last resort!

Comment: I'm pretty bad concerning apache conf, I can't help you this way. Let's hope someone has a better solution